# GGTS 3.5.0 crashes when in debug mode

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I have a GGTS  3.5.0.RELEASE version. When I try to run my code in debug mode, and try to move to the next line using F6 command, it crashes. Any idea?

I have **grails.project.fork** commented in BuildConfig.groovy

Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 
Version: 3.5.0.RELEASE

## Getting following ERROR:

---

### GGTS

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaw.exe
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-jar D:\JAVA\springsource\ggts-3.4.0.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher D:\JAVA\springsource\ggts-3.4.0.RELEASE\GGTS.exe
-name GGTS
--launcher.library D:\JAVA\springsource\ggts-3.4.0.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup D:\JAVA\springsource\ggts-3.4.0.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 18f8_6c
-product org.springsource.ggts.ide
-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-jar D:\JAVA\springsource\ggts-3.4.0.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

============